# iTextSharp class for export pdf gridview in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, itext

With this c# code I need export in PDF format an GridView.

I use iTextSharp class.

My problem is the last column of gridview where I have set the Hyperlink tag.

In the export pdf the image of Hyperlink It is not aligned within the corresponding cell, because moved to the right all the values of the other cells.

Please check the attached image.

[image]

Anybody know how can I resolve this?

Can you suggest any other method?

Thank you in advance.

Please check the code below.

```
   for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < gvProducts.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < gvProducts.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                if (j == 10)
                {
                    cellText = (gvProducts.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[10].FindControl("img") as HyperLink).NavigateUrl;
                    string imagePath = Server.MapPath((gvProducts.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[10].FindControl("img") as HyperLink).ImageUrl);
                    iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagePath);
                    Chunk cImage = new Chunk(image, 0, 0, false);
                    Anchor anchor = new Anchor(cImage);
                    anchor.Reference = cellText.ToString();
                    table.AddCell(anchor);
                }
                else
                {
                    cellText = Server.HtmlDecode(gvProducts.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[j].Text);
                }

                cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cellText, FontFactory.GetFont("PrepareForExport", 8)));                  
                cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
                cell.FixedHeight = 25f;
                table.AddCell(cell);
            }
        }
```

**Edit #1**

```
protected void ExportToPDFWithFormatting()
{
        PdfPTable table = null; 

        int colCount = gvProducts.Columns.Count;

        table = new PdfPTable(colCount);
        table.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        table.WidthPercentage = 100;

        int[] colWidths = new int[gvProducts.Columns.Count];

        PdfPCell cell;
        string cellText;

        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < colCount; colIndex++)
        {

            colWidths[colIndex] = (int)gvProducts.Columns[colIndex].ItemStyle.Width.Value;
            cellText = Server.HtmlDecode(gvProducts.HeaderRow.Cells[colIndex].Text);

            BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(
                                    BaseFont.HELVETICA,
                                    BaseFont.CP1252,
                                    BaseFont.EMBEDDED,
                                    false);

            iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, BaseColor.WHITE);
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cellText.Replace("<br />", Environment.NewLine), font));

            cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
            cell.FixedHeight = 55f;

            cell.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#a52a2a"));

            table.AddCell(cell);
        }


        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < gvProducts.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
        {
            if (gvProducts.Rows[rowIndex].RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < gvProducts.Columns.Count; j++)
                {

                   if (j == 10)
                   {

                       cellText = (gvProducts.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[10].FindControl("img") as HyperLink).NavigateUrl;
                       string imagePath = Server.MapPath((gvProducts.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[10].FindControl("img") as HyperLink).ImageUrl);
                       iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagePath);
                       Chunk cImage = new Chunk(image, 0, 0, false);
                       Anchor anchor = new Anchor(cImage);
                       anchor.Reference = cellText.ToString();
                       table.AddCell(anchor);

                   }
                   else
                   {
                      cellText = Server.HtmlDecode(gvProducts.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[j].Text);
                   }

                      cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cellText, FontFactory.GetFont("PrepareForExport", 8)));                  
                      cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                      cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
                      cell.FixedHeight = 25f;
                      table.AddCell(cell);

                }
            }
        }

    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A3.Rotate(), 30f, 30f, 30f, 0f);

    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);

    pdfDoc.Open();
    table.HeaderRows = 1;

    iTextSharp.text.Font fdefault = FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 18, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLUE);

    string s;
    s = "Test Export";

    pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph(s, fdefault));
    pdfDoc.Add(table);

    pdfDoc.Close();

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;" + "filename=" + DateTime.Now + ".pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();

}
```

**Edit #2**

```
<table class="mGrid" cellspacing="0" align="Center" rules="all" border="1" id="gvProducts" style="width:500px;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
                    <th scope="col">A</th>
                    <th scope="col">B</th>
                    <th scope="col">C</th>
                    <th scope="col">D</th>
                    <th scope="col">E</th>
                    <th scope="col">F</th>
                    <th scope="col">G</th>
                    <th scope="col">H</th>
                    <th scope="col">L</th>
                    <th scope="col">M</th>


    </tr>

            <tr style="background-color:#DCF5F5;">
        <td><input type="image" name="gvProducts$ctl02$imgbtnEdit" id="gvProducts_imgbtnEdit_0" src="/images/edit.gif" /></td>          
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">1</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">2</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">3</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">4</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">5</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">6</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">7</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">138,79</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">NO</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left"><a id="gvProducts_img_0"><img src="/Images/cross-button.png" /></a></td>
    </tr>



            <tr style="background-color:#DCF5F5;">
        <td><input type="image" name="gvProducts$ctl03$imgbtnEdit" id="gvProducts_imgbtnEdit_1" src="/images/edit.gif" /></td>          
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">1</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">2</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">3</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">4</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">5</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">6</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">7</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">138,80</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">NO</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left"><a id="gvProducts_img_1"><img src="/Images/cross-button.png" /></a></td>
    </tr>




            <tr style="background-color:#DCF5F5;">
        <td><input type="image" name="gvProducts$ctl04$imgbtnEdit" id="gvProducts_imgbtnEdit_2" src="/images/edit.gif" /></td>          
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">1</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">2</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">3</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">4</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">5</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">6</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">7</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">138,81</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">NO</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left"><a id="gvProducts_img_2"><img src="/Images/cross-button.png" /></a></td>
    </tr>


            <tr style="background-color:#DCF5F5;">
        <td><input type="image" name="gvProducts$ctl05$imgbtnEdit" id="gvProducts_imgbtnEdit_3" src="/images/edit.gif" /></td>          
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">1</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">2</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">3</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">4</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">5</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">6</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">7</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">138,82</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left">NO</td>  
                     <td class="ddl_Class_new" align="left"><a id="gvProducts_img_3"><img src="/Images/cross-button.png" /></a></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

**Edit #3**

```
                <asp:GridView ID="gvProducts" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EmptyDataText="Empty"
                    runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="mGrid" Width="500" HorizontalAlign="Center"
                    OnRowEditing="gvProducts_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvProducts_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="gvProducts_RowUpdating"
                    OnRowDataBound="gvProducts_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="gvProducts_RowDeleting"
                    OnSorting="gvProducts_Sorting" AllowSorting="true" OnPageIndexChanging="gvProducts_PageIndexChanging">

                    <Columns>

                        <%--Start 0--%>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEdit" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" ImageUrl="/images/edit.gif"
                                    ToolTip="Edit" OnClientClick="return confirm('confirm?');" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnUpdate" CommandName="Update" runat="server" ImageUrl="/images/update.gif"
                                    ToolTip="Update" OnClientClick="if(!confirm('confirm?')) return;" />
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="/images/cancel.gif"
                                    ToolTip="Cancel" OnClientClick="return confirm('confirm??');" />
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" ImageUrl="/images/delete.gif"
                                    ToolTip="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('confirm?');" />

                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <%--End 0--%>

                        <asp:BoundField DataField="A" HeaderText="A" ReadOnly="true" HtmlEncode="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-CssClass="ddl_Class_new" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="B" HeaderText="B" ReadOnly="true" HtmlEncode="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-CssClass="ddl_Class_new" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="C" HeaderText="C" ReadOnly="true" HtmlEncode="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-CssClass="ddl_Class_new" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="D" HeaderText="D" ReadOnly="true" HtmlEncode="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-CssClass="ddl_Class_new" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="E" HeaderText="E" ReadOnly="true" HtmlEncode="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-CssClass="ddl_Class_new" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="F" HeaderText="F" ReadOnly="true" HtmlEncode="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-CssClass="ddl_Class_new" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="G" HeaderText="G" ReadOnly="true" HtmlEncode="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-CssClass="ddl_Class_new" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="H" HeaderText="H" ReadOnly="true" HtmlEncode="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-CssClass="ddl_Class_new" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="L" HeaderText="L" ReadOnly="true" HtmlEncode="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-CssClass="ddl_Class_new" />

                        <%--Start 10--%>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="attached" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:HyperLink ID="img" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("attached").ToString() %>'
                                    ImageUrl='<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("attached").ToString()) ? "/images/cross-button.png" : "/images/download.gif")%>'
                                    ToolTip='<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("attached").ToString()) ? "No available" : "Available")%>'
                                    Target="_blank" BorderStyle="None" ForeColor="Transparent">
                                </asp:HyperLink>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <%--End 10--%>


                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Please provide full function, Here some variables are not declare in this code.

Comment: @Sunny Okay thank you; in Edit #1 in my first question full function

Comment: Great 1 more thing i want to see Gridview HTML.

Comment: @Sunny Okay thank you; in Edit #2 in my first question Gridview HTML

Comment: I am asking about gridview aspx code not browser html

Comment: @Sunny Okay so sorry ... thank you; in Edit #3 in my first question Gridview code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created one sample:
[image: PDF Sample]
Here you can see image hyperlink is placed in proper place. i am using static values here as i am not able to generate proper conditions as per your grid columns.

**CS:**

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // ExportToPDFWithFormatting();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

    using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
    {
        try
        {
            // create the PDF document
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, m);

            // open document to add content
            document.Open();

            generatePDF(document);

            // close the document
            document.Close();

            // stream the PDF to the user
            Response.OutputStream.Write(m.GetBuffer(), 0, m.GetBuffer().Length);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    //Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=AdHockTask.pdf");
    Response.End();
}
private void generatePDF(Document document)
{
    iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/close.png"));
    #region title
    PdfPTable title = new PdfPTable(3);
    title.TotalWidth = 550;
    title.LockedWidth = true;
    int[] headerwidths = { 20, 50, 30 }; // percentage
    title.SetWidths(headerwidths);

    title.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    title.DefaultCell.Border = 0;
    title.DefaultCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;

    title.AddCell(img);
    title.AddCell(new Phrase("Report", FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 12, Font.BOLD)));

    PdfPCell PintDate = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Print Date: " + "  " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 9, Font.NORMAL)));
    //PdfPCell RepID = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(currRepID, FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 10, Font.BOLD)));
    PintDate.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
    PintDate.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
    PintDate.Border = 0;
    title.AddCell(PintDate);
    document.Add(title);

    #endregion

    #region detail
    PdfPTable detail = new PdfPTable(5);
    detail.TotalWidth = 550f;
    detail.LockedWidth = true;
    float[] headerwidths1 = { 23, 12, 15, 15, 15 }; // percentage
    detail.SetWidths(headerwidths1);
    //detail.HeaderRows = 1;
    detail.SplitLate = false;
    //document.Add(new Paragraph(" "));
    PdfPCell eqipment = new PdfPCell();
    eqipment.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    eqipment.Colspan = 8;
    eqipment.PaddingBottom = 5f;

    PdfPTable EqipmentTable = GeneratePdfEquipmentPartsReplacement();
    eqipment.AddElement(EqipmentTable);
    detail.AddCell(eqipment);
    #endregion

    document.Add(detail);
}

private PdfPTable GeneratePdfEquipmentPartsReplacement()
{

    PdfPTable tblEquipmentPartsReplacement = new PdfPTable(5);
    tblEquipmentPartsReplacement.TotalWidth = 550;
    tblEquipmentPartsReplacement.LockedWidth = true;
    int[] PartsUsedDuringRepairWidths = { 9, 13, 17, 9, 10 }; // percentage
    tblEquipmentPartsReplacement.SetWidths(PartsUsedDuringRepairWidths);
    tblEquipmentPartsReplacement.DefaultCell.Border = 1;
    tblEquipmentPartsReplacement.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    tblEquipmentPartsReplacement.DefaultCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;

    #region Header Section

    PdfPCell cellEquipmentPartsReplacement = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Table Header", FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 10, Font.BOLD)));
    cellEquipmentPartsReplacement.Colspan = 9;
    cellEquipmentPartsReplacement.BackgroundColor = new Color(180, 180, 180);
    cellEquipmentPartsReplacement.PaddingBottom = 5f;
    tblEquipmentPartsReplacement.AddCell(cellEquipmentPartsReplacement);

    #endregion

    #region Grid's Headers

    PdfPCell cellPartIDAH = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Column 1", FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 9, Font.BOLD)));
    cellPartIDAH.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    cellPartIDAH.BackgroundColor = new Color(235, 235, 235);

    PdfPCell cellEquipPartsAH = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Column 2", FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 9, Font.BOLD)));
    cellEquipPartsAH.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    cellEquipPartsAH.BackgroundColor = new Color(235, 235, 235);

    PdfPCell cellPartNumberAH = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("HyperLink", FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 9, Font.BOLD)));
    cellPartNumberAH.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    cellPartNumberAH.BackgroundColor = new Color(235, 235, 235);

    PdfPCell cellSerialAH = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Column 4", FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 9, Font.BOLD)));
    cellSerialAH.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    cellSerialAH.BackgroundColor = new Color(235, 235, 235);

    PdfPCell cellDescriptionAH = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("HyperLink", FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 9, Font.BOLD)));
    cellDescriptionAH.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    cellDescriptionAH.BackgroundColor = new Color(235, 235, 235);

    /////////////////////////////////////////
    tblEquipmentPartsReplacement.AddCell(cellPartIDAH);
    tblEquipmentPartsReplacement.AddCell(cellEquipPartsAH);
    tblEquipmentPartsReplacement.AddCell(cellPartNumberAH);
    tblEquipmentPartsReplacement.AddCell(cellSerialAH);
    tblEquipmentPartsReplacement.AddCell(cellDescriptionAH);


    #endregion

    #region Grid's Values

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        //Equipment
        PdfPCell cellPartIDAV = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("partid- " + i, FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 8)));
        cellPartIDAV.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
        tblEquipmentPartsReplacement.AddCell(cellPartIDAV);

        PdfPCell cellEquipPartsAV = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("test- " + i, FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 8)));
        cellEquipPartsAV.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
        tblEquipmentPartsReplacement.AddCell(cellEquipPartsAV);

        iTextSharp.text.Image image1 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/close.png"));
        Chunk cImage1 = new Chunk(image1, 0, 0, false);
        Anchor anchor1 = new Anchor(cImage1);
        anchor1.Reference = "www.google.com";
        tblEquipmentPartsReplacement.AddCell(anchor1);

        PdfPCell cellSerialAV = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("test- " + i, FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 8)));
        cellSerialAV.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
        tblEquipmentPartsReplacement.AddCell(cellSerialAV);

        iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/close.png"));
        Chunk cImage = new Chunk(image, 0, 0, false);
        Anchor anchor = new Anchor(cImage);
        anchor.Reference = "www.yahoo.com";
        tblEquipmentPartsReplacement.AddCell(anchor);
    }


    return tblEquipmentPartsReplacement;
    #endregion

    //////////////////////////////////////////////
    //document.Add(tblEquipmentPartsReplacement);

}
```

Please cross check with your close button image may be it is taking space in down side.

This is my image which i am using:

[image]

Hope you will modify this code as per your need. 
Hope this will resolve your problem.

Comment: Thank you Sir but in my case your suggestion not working. I close this thread.

Comment: Sorry for that, I had try my best to resolve your issue. Hope in future i will help you.